# access data from table in many to many relationship in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have three table's student , course , student_course

```
table student
{
    student_id(PK)
}

table course
{
   course_id(PK)
}

table student_course
{
   student_id(PK+FK)
   course_id(PK+FK)
}
```

I created model class's and configuration files using Hibernate Generation Tool.
It create following files-

```
1) student.java & student.hbm.xml
2) course.java & course.hbm.xml
```

And for **student_course it creates set in each hbm file with Many-to-Many relationship**.
So I want Course object's related to student, for this i want to access student_course table separately.

Right Now i access Course object related to student by accessing  set of student_course through student object.I think it is not efficient one.

What is the efficient way to this?

Can i do this
**by writing sql query** or
**by manually creating studentCourse.java & studentCourse.hbm.xml**

please suggest me efficient way to access course object's related to student object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> please suggest me efficient way to access course object's related to
>   student object.

I think what you've got it the right approach. There is a link table but Hibernate has hidden it through the use of a ManyToMany - this is the correct modelling for this relationship. A student can take many courses and a course has many students.